# HSP/HFP profiles doesnt work on bluetooth headphones

Tags: sound, bluetooth, microphone, headphones, headset

I have conected a bluetooth headset (N35) to the computer in Ubuntu 21.10, and I can hear them fine with A2DP.  But if I select HSP or HFP, they don't work, I can only hear a strange noise, and the microphone doesn't work.

I've seen similar questions with this topic, but the answers doesn't work for me.  Anyone can help?

```
lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 1058:25ee Western Digital Technologies, Inc. My Book 25EE
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0626 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB3.1 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL88x2bu [AC1200 Techkey] 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045e:076d Microsoft Corp. LifeCam HD-5000
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub*

sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
[    0.108350] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.156094] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.300065] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80
[    0.300073] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80
[    4.273689] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.273703] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.273706] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.273708] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.273710] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.407006] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds and force-suspending once...
[    7.682812] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    7.682815] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    7.682818] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   16.175172] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   16.175201] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   16.175204] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: I have edited the question with de results

Comment: 20.10 is no longer supported and a newer version with a newer kernel might fix it

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake, ubuntu version is 21.10